# Getting syntax error in a Sql query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, syntax-error

Hello everyone i am trying to compare a user input id with a db id but when 
i execute the query i get syntax error what am i doing wrong?

```
 sql = "SELECT individual.id " 
                + "FROM individual"
                + "WHERE individual.id = ? ";
       PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       pst.setInt(1, input);

    while(rs.next()){
        int Iid = rs.getInt("id");
        System.out.println(Iid);
    }
```

Error message

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id = ?' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2738)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1617)
```

Comment: A bit far fetched, but what do you get if you replace `"FROM individual"` with `"FROM individual "`?

Comment: This code does not throw this  exception. You aren't calling `executeQuery()` anywhere, as shown in the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

```
+ "FROM individual" + "WHERE individ
```

Will be resolved to

```
  FROM individualWHERE individ...
```

Add spaces to your string and you should be fine